# Problem with template specialisation for a derived class

Tags: c++, templates

When I compile the following

```
#include <iostream>

#define XXX 1
#define YYY 2

class X
{
public:

    template< int FLD >
    void func();
};

template<> void X::func< XXX >()
{
    std::cout << "X::func< " << XXX << " >" << std::endl;
}

class Y : public X
{
public:
};

template<> void Y::func< YYY >()
{
    std::cout << "Y::func< " << YYY << " >" << std::endl;
}

template<> void Y::func< XXX >()
{
    std::cout << "Y::func< " << XXX << " >" << std::endl;
}

int main( int c, char *v[] )
{
    X x;

    Y y;
}
```

I get

```
x.cpp:24: error: template-id 'func<2>' for 'void Y::func()' does not match any template declaration
x.cpp:24: error: invalid function declaration
x.cpp:29: error: template-id 'func<1>' for 'void Y::func()' does not match any template declaration
x.cpp:29: error: invalid function declaration
```

I'm trying to specialise a template in a base class.

Can anyone explain either how it's done or why I can't do it.

Thx
Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it, as you cannot do the following either and for the same reason, `Y::func` is not declared in `Y`:

```
class X {
public: 
   void foo();
};
void X::foo() {}
class Y : public X {
};
void Y::foo() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no methods with name  func() declared in class Y, so compiler can not find any  Y::func() declaration